# Isolation of linux distro (ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04) in wsl

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows 10 I have installed 2 type of linux distro ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04 using WSL.
I want to configure 20.04 for ssh port 22 and 18.04 for ssh port 2222 .
Will doing these changes affect either distro?

**When we installed these distro are they isolated or will they affect each other ?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Try to configure as you want. If you have a problem then ask a question. What is stopping you from trying?

Comment: To best advise you on how to configure SSH on these two instances, it would really help if you explained the use-case you are going for.  What are the two instances being used for?  What is your intention in installing SSH in each instance?  For WSL, there's often a better solution than SSH for most use-cases.

Comment: Also, are these WSL1 or WSL2 instances?  The configuration of SSH differs greatly between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the SSH port as much as you like on either (or both) of your systems. It will have no impact; your systems will run normally with the changed port settings.

SSH is for *your* interaction with the system. No internal process uses it. A stock install of Ubuntu Desktop doesn't even have an SSH server at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the "simple answer" which answers your question, but probably doesn't really help you all that much.  And then there's the "what you really need to do to run an SSH server on WSL."

Simple answer, as others have already said -- Each instance can operate its own SSH server in relative isolation.

Longer answer ... it's *complicated*.  Running an SSH server on WSL is one thing.  Actually being able to connect to it remotely is another thing entirely.  You have to worry about port forwarding, firewalls, and service start-up (not something that WSL does well in the absence of systemd).

First, it would be helpful to know your use-case(s) for ssh in WSL.

If you just want to access your instances remotely, then I find it is easiest to just [install the Windows 10 OpenSSH server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) on the host itself.  With this in place, the only real configuration you need to do is open port 22 on the Windows Firewall.  And the one-liner for that is included in the Microsoft instructions linked above for the install.

With OpenSSH server installed in Windows, you can use:

```
ssh -t <user@windows_host_or_ip> wsl -d <wsl_instance_name>
```

... to get to your WSL instance.  The `-d <wsl_instance_name>` isn't needed for your default WSL instance.

But perhaps you have some other reason for needing SSH access to the WSL instances.  For instance, I use Ansible to connect to and configure some of my WSL instances across multiple machines.  This requires a "real" SSH server be running for each instance.

In that case, you need to come up with solutions for:

- Port-forwarding from the Windows host to WSL2 instances (WSL1 does not require port forwarding, as its network runs "bridged" with the Windows network interface.)
- Starting the `sshd` service in each instance (it isn't automatic)

In my opinion, the easiest solution here is still to install Windows OpenSSH server on port 22, then configure each WSL instance with its own OpenSSH server as well, but (of course) on different ports.  You can then use the Windows host as a "jumphost" for accessing the instances inside it.  Detailed directions for this can be found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1622603/1210833) on Super User.

This also solves the "starting `sshd` in WSL`problem, because you can use a syntax similar to the earlier one I mentioned (using the`wsl` command *through* Windows ssh) to start the service remotely.  In other words, as long as the Windows SSH server is set to start automatically, you can use this to start any of the WSL instances SSH servers.  The details, again, can be found in that answer.

Also worth reading is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833) on Super User regarding general port forwarding scenarios in WSL.